# sas, simplest task: assign input value to a global variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

A bit confused how to assign an input value to a variable I can pass further to macros or to work with outside the "data" statement, such as a global variable.

This is the code:

```
&let gvar=;

%macro mm ( in1 );
%put &in1;
%mend;

data _null_;
infile stdin;
input resp $ ;
/* This works, displaying the value user has entered */
put resp;
/* This passes the word "resp" instead of a received value */
%mm (resp);
/* This passes a blank value instead of a received value */
%mm (&resp);
/* This also assigns the word "resp" instead of a received value */
%let gvar=resp;
stop;
run;

%put &gvar;
```

Output:

```
$ Value11

Value11
resp
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference RESP not resolved.
resp
```

Per Tom's suggestion, this is the working piece, however, for some reason two lines are read from stdin, instead of 1.

```
data _null_;
infile stdin obs=1;
input resp $ ;
call symputx('gvar',resp,'g');
/* I do have to put/uncomment the stop instruction below to force a single-line input */
*stop;
run;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  The part you say works is just reading up to 8 characters into a dataset variable, but since you are using a null data step the value will disappear.  Are you just looking for the `call symputx()` function that allows you to create a macro variable in a data step?

Comment: Where are trying to "input" this value from?

Comment: standard input, interactively

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to get SAS to read from the unix concept of standard input? Why?  If you are running a SAS program from the command line just use the `-set` command line option to set an environment variable and the `sysget()` or `%sysget()` function to read the value of the environment variable.

Comment: Users are entering custom data from command prompt, which is what sas is then processing, this the idea.

Comment: I am not sure I still understand.  I wouldn't consider information type at a terminal window as "data".  Are you saying you have script (say a shell script or some other language) that is prompting users to answer some questions and you want to pass the answers?  If so then it would probably be easier to pass the answers in environment variables.  If you actually have a lot of data that you want to pass then you could read it into a dataset.  In that case you could read from stdin or pass the name of the file to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with what you say works and add code to create a macro variable from the value in the data step.  Use the CALL SYMPUTX() function.  To force the macro variable into the global symbol table (even if you are running the data step inside of a macro scope) use the optional third parameter.

```
data _null_;
  infile stdin obs=1;
  input resp $ ;
  call symputx('gvar',resp,'g');
run;
```

Comment: Works, just as desired, thank you. 1 question though - if I use obs=1, it reads two lines instead of one, unless I put the hard stop after symputx. Is there a reason for a two-line read?

Comment: Most data steps do not end at the end of the step. Instead they end when it reads past the end of the input.  So the INPUT statement will execute twice, but since the second time will be reading past the end of the input because the OBS=1 option is limiting it to one line it will stop there and the CALL SYMPUTX() function will run only once.